# UNITY: Getting random point on `NavMesh`

Tags: unity-game-engine

### The Problem

My goal is to write a static method that gets an evenly distributed random point on a NavMesh.

I expect for everytime I call this method to get a random `Vector3` that is a point on the mesh, which is currently working, however, the distribution leaves much to be desired.

### Logistics

`Unity 2022.3.19f1`.

Some information about the floor object

**Here is the parent transform**
[image: Image of Parent Transforms]

**Here is the child, aka the actual mesh**

[image: Child Components]

To summarize textually when i get `localScale` it's 1,1,1 and `lossyScale` is 200,200,200

### Code

```cs
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;


public static class SpawnUtils
{
    //Offset to ensure GameObjects aren't spawned near edge
    private const int NAV_MESH_OFFSET = 20;
    private const int MAX_ATTEMPTS = 5;
    private static GameObject floor;

    public static Vector3 GetRandomSpawnPosition()
    {
        GameObject floor = GetFloor();

        NavMeshHit hit = new();
        int attempts = 0;
        bool foundPoint = false;
        
        float maxX = floor.transform.position.x + floor.transform.lossyScale.x / 2 - NAV_MESH_OFFSET;
        float maxZ = floor.transform.position.z + floor.transform.lossyScale.z / 2 - NAV_MESH_OFFSET;
        float minX = floor.transform.position.x - floor.transform.lossyScale.x / 2 + NAV_MESH_OFFSET;
        float minZ = floor.transform.position.z - floor.transform.lossyScale.z / 2 + NAV_MESH_OFFSET;

       // see my note on this variable 
        float maxDistance = 100;


        while (!foundPoint && attempts < MAX_ATTEMPTS)
        {
            float x = UnityEngine.Random.Range(minX, maxX);
            float z = UnityEngine.Random.Range(minZ, maxZ);
            float y = floor.transform.position.y + floor.transform.lossyScale.y / 2;
            Vector3 randomPoint = new(x, y, z);
            foundPoint = NavMesh.SamplePosition(randomPoint, out hit, maxDistance, NavMesh.AllAreas);
            attempts++;
        }

        if (!foundPoint)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Failed to find a spawnable area within the maximum number, {MAX_ATTEMPTS} attempts.");
            return floor.transform.position;
        }

        return hit.position;
    }


    public static GameObject Floor
    {
       ...
    }


    public static GameObject GetFloor()
    {
       ...
    }

    public static Vector3 GetSpawnableArea(Vector3 origin, float maxDistance)
    {

       ...
    }

}
```

Regarding `float maxDistance`, this variable appears the be most influential and the cause of most of my misunderstanding, I imagined that it just tells the `SamplePosition` method how far of a search range to go from `randomPoint` and stop once the minimum distance required is found.

However, there seems to be a discrepancy here, adjusting the variable in increments of 50 leads to everything spawning either at the edge or in the dead center.

**Examples**

`maxDistance = 1000`
[image: Example with maxDistance = 1000 GameObjects` are distributed towards the edges]

`maxDistance = 500`
[image: Example with maxDistance = 500, GameObjects are distributed towards the edges]

**Now here it begins to get sensitive**

`maxDistance = 200`
[image: maxDistance = 200, still a edges]

`maxDistance = 150`
[image: maxDistance = 150, still at edges]

Now once, I'm at this 100 mark, I encounter this strange distribution where objects are spawned at the center AND edges

[image: macDistance = 100]

I'll spare the last image since from 80 downwards, it's almost consistently at the origin `Vector3(0,0,0)`

Comment: A couple of thoughts here; the scale seems large, in which case you might get interpolation errors. Next the + / - cases potentially seem no different when the source is Vec3.zero. Lastly (and you seem a competent coder so you already know the benefits) there are built in methods e.g: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random-insideUnitCircle.html

Comment: if you are hoping to space them round the edge of the circle, at regular intervals you would need to calculate the degrees apart they needed to be and then try and put them  there